# How to define multiple domains in owlready2?

Tags: python, dns, owl, ontology, owlready

I'm new with owlread2.
I'm want to implement a relationship like

```
Car has Color
Bike has Color
House has Color
```

so far i tried it like this:

```
class has_color(ObjectProperty):
   domain = [Car,Bike,House]
   range = [Color]
```

and

```
cass has_color(ObjectProperty):
    domain = [Car| Bike| House]
    range = [Color]
```

but both these methods don't seem to work.
I would be happy if someone can tell me how to make this work

Comment: Either `Or([Class1, Class2])` or `Class1 | Class2` are the correct syntax for the union of classes. "Don't seem to work" is also not meaningful ... what does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i kept digging, i found the solution.
the Or() statement needs to be in brackets.

```
class has_color(ObjectProperty):
       domain = [Or([Car,Bike,House])]
       range = [Color]
```

works like a charm.

```
domain = [Car | Bike | House]
```

also works, but some IDEs mark the vertical bar as deprecated