# owlready2: create FunctionalProperty to multiple classes

Tags: python, parameter-passing, ontology, knowledge-graph, owlready

I need a FunctionalProperty to classes like this in Python using owlready2:

```
    class student(Thing):
        pass

    class teacher(Thing):
        pass
```

and so on, I have six of them.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70061671/how-to-define-multiple-domains-in-owlready2) and the solution was this:

```
class has_color(ObjectProperty):
       domain = [Or([Car,Bike,House])]
       range = [Color]
```

or

```
domain = [Car | Bike | House]
```

But I have five classes and I get this error message:

Exception has occurred: TypeError
LogicalClassConstruct.**init**() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 6 were given

To reproduce it, just create six class and run this:

```
    class has_value(FunctionalProperty):
        domain = [
            Or(myclass1, myclass2, myclass3, myclass4, myclass5, myclass6)
        ]
        range = [float]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the owlready2 library, but it seems you've missed some brackets from the example. The example defines the domain as

```
Or([Car,Bike,House])
```

So your domain should be written as

```
Or([myclass1, myclass2, myclass3, myclass4, myclass5, myclass6])
```

Note the square brackets around the class list.